# Remove only the last _ in a string using split()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, split

trying to get table cell edit fixed i have the following code which if a string supposing has test_1_ then it removes all _ but i only want to remove the last _ and it should look like this test_1

here is the js part which needs some expert touch

```
 // Get edit id, field name and value
  var id = this.id;
  var split_id = id.split("_");
  var field_name = split_id[0];
  var edit_id = split_id[1];
  var value = $(this).val();
```

my html looks like this

```
<input type='text' class='txtedit' value='<?php echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s a', strtotime($row['time_in'])); ?>' id='time_in_<?php echo $row['hours']; ?>' >
```

now if you notice the input field id looks like id='time_in_' but after split i want time_in to remain remove only the last _

hope you get my point?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is the `_` you want to remove always at the end of the string?  If not, what do you want to happen to characters after the last `_` in the string?

Comment: yes every last _ i need to remove, say e.g test_1_  or abc_xya_ i want the outputs as test_1 and abc_xya. rest of my above code should remain functional as it is only the last _ is what i need to remove

Comment: You didn't answer either of the questions I asked.

Comment: oh sorry i have it fixed already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to convert it to an array and rejoin it as a string. You can use simple string methods to get the result.

```
let id = "test_1_";
console.log(id.slice(0, id.lastIndexOf('_')));
```

Comment: `.slice()` will return a new `Array`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant `substring()` here, not `slice()`

Comment: @ScottMarcus I am using String's slice method so it wont return a new array.

Comment: @DanielBeck You are correct we can either use slice or substring but slice is more reliable when it comes to handling edge cases. Hence I answered using slice method.

Comment: @AnkitBhatia That's interesting.  Can you expand on what "edge cases" you're talking about?

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string at the `_` characters, which will remove all the `_` characters and return an array of the separate parts on both sides of each `_`, but this will result in an empty string as the last item in the array. So, then you can pop that last resulting array item off the array and join the resulting array items back together with `_`, which won't place one at the end:

```js
let s = "This_Is_My_String_";
s = s.split("_");
s.pop();  // pop the last item off the array

s = s.join("_");

console.log(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to remove the last character of the string if it's a _, `split()` is the long way around.  Try this:

`var value = this.id.replace(/_$/, '')`